# How to pass the component that should be used to represent the title in react?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

I am currently working on a component and I need to make the title of the component as generic as possible. I wish to pass the component that would be used, quiet similar to Typography in react mui where you can pass the variant. `<Typography variant="h1">lol</Typography>` so I made the following

```
interface  IPropsCatagory { 
    title: string;
    TitleElement?: React.ElementType | React.FunctionComponent;
}

export  const  Catagory: React.FC<IPropsCatagory> = ({ children, title, TitleElement }) => {
    return (
        <CategoryContainer>
            <TitleElement>{title}</TitleElement>
            {children}
        </CategoryContainer>  
    );
};

Catagory.defaultProps = {
    TitleElement:  'h3',
};
```

I am getting the error: "JSX element type 'TitleElement' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)". does anyone got a solution to the problem? I tried to read other people who posted about it but every solution i used didn't work for me.

Comment: Remember that the syntax `<MyComponent></MyComponent>` is equivalent to calling a function that returns an element that can be rendered to the DOM. In this case you've defined `TitleElement` to be an element itself rather than a function that returns an element.

Comment: it sound funny but I totally forgot that. thank you Jimmy